# filter data on basis of modal in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The below code is a modal having two custom dropdown components text input and a button and after the button is clicked it just filters data from an API.

I am using. I am trying to write a filter function but it is just not working.

```js
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import IonIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import {COLORS} from '../../../constants';
import {Quicksand_FONTS, width} from '../../../constants/theme';
import DropDown from './component/Dropdown';
import AgencyType from './component/AgencyType';

const AgencyFilterModal = ({setOpen,data, loading}) => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [agencyType, setAgencyType] = useState('');
  const [agencyName, setAgencyName] = useState('');
  const handleSearch = () => {
    const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
      let cityFilter = true;
      let agencyTypeFilter = true;
      let agencyNameFilter = true;

      if (city && item.city.toLowerCase() !== city.toLowerCase()) {
        cityFilter = false;
      }

      if (
        agencyType &&
        item.agencyType.toLowerCase() !== agencyType.toLowerCase()
      ) {
        agencyTypeFilter = false;
      }

      if (
        agencyName &&
        !item.agencyName.toLowerCase().includes(agencyName.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        agencyNameFilter = false;
      }

      return cityFilter && agencyTypeFilter && agencyNameFilter;
    });
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        isVisible={true}
        backdropColor={COLORS.dark}
        animationIn="slideInUp"
        onBackdropPress={() => setOpen(false)}
        scrollOffset={40}
        style={styles.modal}>
        <View style={styles.modalWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.modal_line}></Text>

          <DropDown
            placeholder="All Cities"
            selectedValue={city}
            onValueChange={itemValue => setCity(itemValue)}
          />

          <AgencyType placeholder="All Agencies" />
          <View style={styles.bottomBox_container}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Search agencies"
              value={agencyType}
              onChangeText={name => setAgencyName(name)}
              style={styles.LastInout}
            />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={filteredData}>
            <IonIcons
              name="search"
              size={25}
              color={COLORS.light}
              style={styles.button}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AgencyFilterModal;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the handleSearch function, you're using filteredData as a function, when it's actually a variable. You should call the handleSearch function to filter the data and set the setOpen value to false. Update the onPress of the search button like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={handleSearch}>
```

This will correctly trigger the filtering process when the button is pressed.

Keep in mind that the filteredData variable doesn't seem to be defined in the provided code. If you intended to use a different variable or function here, make sure it's properly defined and serves the purpose of filtering the data.